# When post job-relevant news on LinkedIn

Tags: linkedin

I attended a course paid by my company and I'd like to share it on LinkedIn.

Is it relevant at which time I do the post on LinkedIn? Is the day after on a friday evening still ok?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Depends. Prior to the meeting did you sign a NDA and/or during the meeting did they bring up anything internal or discussed any on going internal projects? If so, I would caution against posting that.

Comment: Thank you Dan. The question is not if but when publish the news.  It's just a course about Time Management.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I've got 2 concerns: 1)is it professional/respectful enough to wait or shall it be the soonest after the course? 2) Will the news have impact/readers on a weekend compared to under the week?

Comment: @Amu: nobody really cares when you make the updates. The information is what counts.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share just the fact that you attended a course, you can do it at any time you want.

If you want to share the content of the materials (presentations, pdf files...), then you should just calm down and change your mind. Those materials are copyrighted and you risk getting yourself in serious trouble.

"Making available" someone else's work without the prior written consent of the owner is illegal in most (all?) civilized countries. If it is on LinkedIn or on torrents, it does not really matter.

Comment: Thanks virolino, I wont publish the course itself, just the news that I attended the course. About the picture, I was thinking of my course certificate (with info on the content/skills trained) but I coud also just publish the cours' title with the logo of the company.

Comment: Actually, just the title should be OK. If a potential employer wants details, then you can show them "anything" (logo, diploma, any other "public" information...). For anyone else, it does not really matter.

Comment: OK, thanks everyone. I'll post it without time pressure then :) An of course, with no sensible photo content.